# Linuxで恒久的にタイムスタンプが新しい順に並び替える方法

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Linuxでタイムスタンプが新しい順に並び替えるには
`ls -lt`
でよいと思うのですが、一時的にではなく、恒久的に並びかえる方法はあるでしょうか？
（例えば次にlsコマンドを実行したときにタイムスタンプ順に並びかえた状態で表示されるようにしたいです。）
環境はubuntu16.04です。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

お使いのシェルで**alias**を設定しましょう。

```
# vi ~/.bashrc
alias ls='ls -t'

# . ~/.bashrc
```

上記の例を設定した後なら、`ls -l`と実行すれば`ls -lt`を実行したのと同じになります。